# How to have ratingbar which draws less than half of the star?

Tags: android, ratingbar

```
 <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:numStars="1"
            android:rating="0.2"
            android:stepSize="0.2" />
```

I need one star, by which I want to rate minimum 1 maximum 5 ,that is why I set stepSize 0.2 ,at the begining I set 0.2 as the minimum rate. but it draws that half of the star, clicking on it fills ,but never fills less than half of the star.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 <RatingBar
     android:id="@+id/ratingBar
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     android:isIndicator="true"
     android:numStars="5"
     android:rating="0"
     android:stepSize="0.2"
  />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I too am struggling with this right now. You can set a stepSize to 0.5 or higher but not lower. Im not sure if it is capped at 0.5?